# Problems with awk substr

Tags: awk, split, substr

I am trying to split a file column using the substr awk command. So the input is as follows (it consists of 4 lines, one blank line):

```
@NS500645:122:HYGVMBGX2:4:21402:2606:16446:ACCTAGAAGG:R1
ACCTAGAAGGATATGCGCTTGCGCGTTAGAGATCACTAGAGCTAAGGAATTTGAGATTACAGTAAGCTATGATCC

/AAAAEEEEEEEEEEAAEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

I want to split the second line by the pattern "GATC" but keeping it on the right sub-string like:

```
ACCTAGAAGGATATGCGCTTGCGCGTTAGA   GATCACTAGAGCTAAGGAATTTGAGATTACAGTAAGCTATGATCC
```

I want that the last line have the same length as the splitted one and regenerate the file like:

```
ACCTAGAAGGATATGCGCTTGCGCGTTAGA  
/AAAAEEEEEEEEEEAAEEEAEEEEEEEEE
GATCACTAGAGCTAAGGAATTTGAGATTACAGTAAGCTAT
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE 
GATCC  
EEEEE
```

For split the last colum I am using this awk script:

```
cat prove | paste - - - - | awk 'BEGIN
{FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}\ {gsub("GATC","/tGATC", $2); {split ($2, a, "\t")};\ for
(i in a) print substr($4, length(a[i-1])+1,
length(a[i-1])+length(a[i]))}'
```

But the output is as follows:

```
/AAAAEEEEEEEEEEAAEEEAEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Being the second and third line longer that expected.

I check the calculated length that are passed to the substr command and are correct:

```
1 30 
31 70
41 45
```

Using these length the output should be:

```
/AAAAEEEEEEEEEEAAEEEAEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEE
```

But as I showed it is not the case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You say `I want to split the first line by the pattern "GATC"` but the first line, `@NS500645:122:HYGVMBGX2:4:21402:2606:16446:ACCTAGAAGG:R1`, doesn't contain the "GATC". Did you mean you want to split the 2nd line, `ACCTAGAAGGATATGCGCTTGCGCGTTAGAGATCACTAGAGCTAAGGAATTTGAGATTACAGTAAGC`? Also you say your input is 4 lines but then you show 5 lines, and idk what `the + in a separate line` means. Please clean up your question.

Comment: Yes, I want to split 2nd line, and the input contains 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking something like this, but your question formatting is really confusing

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1   {next} 
                   NR==2   {n=index($0,"GATC")} 
                   /^[^+]/ {print substr($0,1,n-1),substr($0,n)}' file

ACCTAGAAGGATATGCGCTTGCGCGTTAGA  GATCACTAGAGCTAAGGAATTTGAGATTACAGTAAGCTATGATCC
/AAAAEEEEEEEEEEAAEEEAEEEEEEEEE  EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

I assumed your file is in this format

```
dummy header line to be ignored
ACCTAGAAGGATATGCGCTTGCGCGTTAGAGATCACTAGAGCTAAGGAATTTGAGATTACAGTAAGCTATGATCC
+
/AAAAEEEEEEEEEEAAEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: Yes the format is as you said. The point is that some times there are two GATC in the first line, so it can be split in three splits.